# SQLite3: Is there a way to select all records using only part of a tuple?

Tags: python, sqlite

I really don't know a good way of asking my question.  What I want to be able to do is search an sqlite3 database with criteria that is determined by a tuple.  The first section is how I would do it normally, and the print statement works as expected:

```
import sqlite3 as sql

conn = sql.connect("Table.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db_table([name] text, [surname] text, [city] text, [state] text)""")
conn.commit()

cur.execute("""INSERT INTO db_table VALUES ("John", "Smith", "New York", "NY")""")
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO db_table VALUES ("Jacob", "Smith", "Chicago", "IL")""")
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO db_table VALUES ("Fred", "Smith", "Buffalo", "NY")""")
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO db_table VALUES ("Greg", "Allen", "Albany", "NY")""")
conn.commit()

search_name_1 = "John"
search_surname_1 = "Smith"
search_city_1 = "New York"
search_state_1 = "NY"
search_1 = (search_name_1, search_surname_1, search_city_1, search_state_1)

cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM db_table WHERE (name, surname, city, state)=(?,?,?,?)""", search_1)
results_1 = cur.fetchall()
print(results_1)
```

If the search criteria were to change (say with is tkinter entry), could I still search using only some of the indices of the tuple?  Like this:

```
import sqlite3 as sql

conn = sql.connect("Table.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db_table([name] text, [surname] text, [city] text, [state] text)""")
conn.commit()

cur.execute("""INSERT INTO db_table VALUES ("John", "Smith", "New York", "NY")""")
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO db_table VALUES ("Jacob", "Smith", "Chicago", "IL")""")
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO db_table VALUES ("Fred", "Smith", "Buffalo", "NY")""")
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO db_table VALUES ("Greg", "Allen", "Albany", "NY")""")
conn.commit()

search_name_2 = "*"
search_surname_2 = "Smith"
search_city_2 = "*"
search_state_2 = "NY"
search_2 = (search_name_2, search_surname_2, search_city_2, search_state_2)

cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM db_table WHERE (name, surname, city, state)=(?,?,?,?)""", search_2)
results_2 = cur.fetchall()
print(results_2)
```

In this case, I would want both John Smith and Fred Smith to print, because they both are Smith and live in NY.

Another example would be if I only entered search_city to be "NY", I would expect John, Fred, and Greg, because they live in NY.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the results, you need to pass some sort of query to the sqlite database, try something like:

```
search_name_2 = ""
search_surname_2 = "Smith"
search_city_2 = ""
search_state_2 = "NY"

cur.execute(f"""SELECT * 
                FROM db_table 
                WHERE name = '{search_name_2}' or 
                      surname = '{search_surname_2}' or
                      city = '{search_city_2}' or
                      state = '{search_state_2}'""")
results_2 = cur.fetchall()
print(results_2)

[('John', 'Smith', 'New York', 'NY'),
 ('Jacob', 'Smith', 'Chicago', 'IL'),
 ('Fred', 'Smith', 'Buffalo', 'NY'),
 ('Greg', 'Allen', 'Albany', 'NY')]
```

Feel free to play around with the query logic. Given your requirements, you might need to create separate queries to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The common way for slightly dynamic queries is to build the query from known blocs. Here I would write:

```
def find(cur, search_name_1, search_surname_1, search_city_1, search_state_1):
    qry = 'SELECT * FROM db_table'
    params = []
    values = []
    if search_name_1 != '*':
        params.append('name')
        values.append(search_name_1)
    if search_surname_1 != '*':
        params.append('surname')
        values.append(search_surname_1)
    if search_city_1 != '*':
        params.append('city')
        values.append(search_city_1)
    if search_state_1 != '*':
        params.append('state')
        values.append(search_state_1)
    if len(params) != 0:
        qry += ' WHERE (' + ','.join(params) + ')=(' + ','.join(['?'] * len(params)) + ')'
    return cur.execute(qry, values).fetchall()
```